# Presenting a UIViewController after local notification

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uilocalnotification

In `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` I initialize a `UINavigationController`. Later, I add the `UINavigationController` to the window:

```
[self.window addSubview:navigationController.view]
```

This all works fine. Now I added local notifications to my app and when the user responds to one, I would like to present a `UIViewController`. So I thought I could override `application:didReceiveLocalNotification:` and in there, use my `navigationController`:

```
[navigationController pushViewController:someVC animated:YES];
```

**However**, this does not work. I did some debugging and noticed that while `navigationController` is not `nil`, `navigationController.view` has no superview, so I assume it is not being displayed.

So, my question is: where should I push my `UIViewController` so that it gets displayed?

Comment: are you using just an app delegate or do you have a viewcontroller file also? If so, I may have a solution for you. My app does the same thing

Comment: @shabzco I have both. Could you explain your solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your AppDelegate.h add this:

```
//Under where you have <UIKit/UIKit.h>
extern NSString *localReceived;
```

In your AppDelegate.m add this:

```
//All the way on top where you import your viewControllers
NSString *localReceived = @"localReceived";
```

In your AppDelegate.m in the `- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)localNotification;`
 method add this:

```
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:localReceived object:self];
```

**Make sure that your viewController is a navigationController**

If it's not, do the following -- Add this piece of code to your `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`:

```
    UINavigationController *nvcontrol = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];

[window addSubview:nvcontrol.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Now -- in your viewController.m add this to your -viewDidLoad function

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(localAction) name:localReceived object:nil];
```

Make a -(void) localAction and in that method add your navigationController code to push to the next View Controller!

Hope that works for you. Works like a charm for me

Answer (score 2):

So here it is, another solution with a different approach. It worked like a charm for me. check it out:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)localNotification{
    UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    CustomViewController *cvc = (CustomViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CustomVC"];
    AnotherViewController *avc = (AnotherViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AnotherVC"];
    avc.someValue = @"Passing a value"; //Optional
    UINavigationController *nav = (UINavigationController *) self.window.rootViewController;
    nav.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:cvc,avc, nil];
    [(UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController popToViewController:avc animated:TRUE];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:localNotification]; 
    //Cancel Just for not showing it anymore on the notifications list...
}
```